# What is the best way to implement Single Sign On (SSO) against Active Directory in ASP.NET WebForms for intranet only application

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, active-directory, single-sign-on

We have intranet application, which is always installed on-premise in customer's environment.

Right now we are using forms authentication and we would like to use continue using it where active directory is not present. However this is a bit irritating to user's of our application because they need to always log in when they are on the machine where the application is installed, even thought it is withing their safe network (with no Internet access etc).

So we would like to have single sign on against active directory, so when they are logged in Windows they will not have to type any passwords when accessing this ASP.NET WebForms application - active directory shall be used (if present of course).